# PHPSpreadSheet : getCalculatedValue() is deprecated, so what's the 'new' way?

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I'm using PHPSpreadSheet, but when I have a column in my Excel sheet like `=B4` and I use `getValue()` in PHPSpreadSheet I literally get that value: "=B4".

So when I look at the source code I see that I can use `getCalculatedValue()`, but that method is deprecated. I can still use it (and it works as expected), but I'm not too fond on using deprecated methods.

So what's in PHPSpreadSheet the proper way to get the correct (referenced) value?

Answer (score 0):

`getCalculatedValue()` has been [un-deprecated a while ago](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/22). So it's fine to use it.

But you should consider upgrading PhpSpreadsheet to its latest commit on develop branch, since you are now working with an old version.